# Linux + how to know which CPU Cores was active last day

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu

recently , we upgrade our redhat server ( version 7 ) from 4 CPU CORE to 32 CPU CORE

is it possible to know which CPU was triggered during last day ?

I mean how to know if the additional CPU that we add are now in process ?

Comment: You can use something like `nmon` to capture resources daily and write it to a file. You can then review the files the next day.

Comment: this tool isn't installed by default , but do we have the ability to capture which cpu are active by - top ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` command would be helpful. Use `top` command to list the utilization of each core.  Press 1 if necessary to split the CPU row into a separate row for each core.

You can also add a column that shows the last-used core for each process.  Press `f` to bring up the field list, then select column **P** and press `d` or `<space>` to toggle the value. Now, press `q` or `<Esc>` to end and see live. In right side you will see a column **P** which shows cpu core no. used by corresponding processor.